# How to sync data from server to local database everyday once in android?

Tags: android

some data is there on the server.I've to sync that data in my local database every day once. Is there any mechanism to do that?

Comment: Would be great if you elobrate more about your scenerio, for now you as per your question I have a suggestion for you to make a Service and make a Broadcast having intent filter of android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED, this is how you can get whenever date change, Make an api call which will call on date change and OnSuccess of that api call store the data in your localDB.

Comment: Thanks, @Tahawakeel.I just gone through this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple ways

1.**Work Manager** (I preferred)  [Doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) it's part of android jetpack. you can add task constraints like batter level,network status,mobile charging.  [Recurring tasks Example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#recurring)

2.Syncadapter

3.broadcast receiver + Service(beware with Android Oreo ) in android 8 you can't start service in background otherwise you have to use foreground service